# Boolean logic simplification of $a * b' * c' * d' + a * b + b * d' + b * c * d$

Tags: propositional-calculus

The expression $a * b' * c' * d' +  a * b + b * d' + b * c * d $ becomes
$a * b + a * c' * d' + b * c + b * d'$, but how can I show that? I can find any laws to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other words

```
a(b+b'c'd')
b(d'+cd)
```

becomes

```
a(b+c'd')
b(d'+c)
```

Can you see why know? If not, try simplifying `x+x'y`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998589/boolean-algebra-prove-that might help.